# How to count a number of times a set of words appear in a given data in t-sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, count

My goal is to get the total number "the", "when", and "wolf" in this dataset.

I would have a total of 14 count in the return query.

Edit: "the" is also added to the count in the word "they"

```
CREATE TABLE #BaseTable([Text] VARCHAR (500))

INSERT INTO #BaseTable ([Text]) VALUES 
('When the villagers heard the cry, they came running up the hill to drive the wolf away.'),
('But, when they arrived, they saw no wolf.'),
('The boy was amused when seeing their angry faces.')
```

The [version of SQL Server](https://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler):

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (Intel X86) 
    Feb 20 2014 19:20:46 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (WOW64) (Hypervisor)
```

Comment: it is not a typical RDBMS task I would say. Anyways, you need to define it with REGEX, as it is a complex task, for example, `They` also contains `the` but you want to exclude it as I understood.

Comment: My apologies for that. How about if I changed the word "the" to "but"? @TedoG.

Edit: "the" in the word "they" is also added in count. Added in the post to

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you want case sensitivity? Do you want to include `they` in `the`?

Comment: I tried counting the words separately but I'm having a trouble to count all three of them @HoneyBadger

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Not sure. I'm just processing in this [online compiler of SQL Server](https://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler) @SteveC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with string functions and a lateral join:

```
select bt.*, x.*
from #basetable bt
cross apply (
    select sum(no_matches) no_matches
    from (
        select (len(bt.text) - len(replace(bt.text, w.word, ''))) / len(w.word) no_matches
        from (values ('the'), ('when'), ('wolf')) w(word)
    ) x
) x
```

If you want just the total number of matches in the resultset, then:

```
select sum(no_matches) total_matches
from #basetable bt
cross apply (
    select (len(bt.text) - len(replace(bt.text, w.word, ''))) / len(w.word) no_matches
    from (values ('the'), ('when'), ('wolf')) w(word)
) x
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2b15a6d4772315b1a791bf82d2f29111)**

Comment: It works!! Thank you! I just have a few question in mind as to how this works.  Is w(word) contained the set "the" "when" and "wolf"?  And what is the use of x at the end? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Guine024: yes, `w` coutans all the words you want to search for. It can easily be extended to handle more words. `x` is an alias for the subquery, that's an important part of SQL language (every derived table must have an alias).

Comment: I see. I will keep this in mind. Thank you so much! Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

You can split the strings and count:

```
select count(*)
from t cross apply
     string_split(replace(replace(t.text, '.', ''), ',', ''), ' ') s
where s.value in ('the', 'when', 'wolf');
```

SQL Server is not optimal for such string operations, but it is possible.

Comment: What error?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15.  If you are using an older version of SQL Server, you can find an equivalent "split" function online.

Comment: Yes I saw the string_split is a function too. Maybe what I'm using is an old version. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A very simplistic approach could look like this:

```
DECLARE @BaseTable TABLE ([Text] VARCHAR(255))

INSERT INTO @BaseTable ([Text]) VALUES 
('When the villagers heard the cry, they came running up the hill to drive the wolf away.'),
('But, when they arrived, they saw no wolf.'),
('The boy was amused when seeing their angry faces.')

DECLARE @Val1 VARCHAR(255) = 'when'
,       @Val2 VARCHAR(255) = 'but'
,       @Val3 VARCHAR(255) = 'wolf'

SELECT  (LEN(BT.Text) - LEN(REPLACE(BT.Text, @Val1, ''))) /LEN(@Val1) 
,       (LEN(BT.Text) - LEN(REPLACE(BT.Text, @Val2, ''))) /LEN(@Val2)
,       (LEN(BT.Text) - LEN(REPLACE(BT.Text, @Val3, ''))) /LEN(@Val3)
FROM    @BaseTable AS BT
```

The idea is to calculate the difference in length when the target word is replaced with nothing. But you don't really want to do this on the database side, if you have a choice.

edit:
Summing all the values is pretty straight forward:

```
SELECT  SUM(val1) + SUM(val2) + SUM(val3)
FROM    (
            SELECT  (LEN(BT.Text) - LEN(REPLACE(BT.Text, @Val1, ''))) /LEN(@Val1) AS val1
            ,       (LEN(BT.Text) - LEN(REPLACE(BT.Text, @Val2, ''))) /LEN(@Val2) AS val2
            ,       (LEN(BT.Text) - LEN(REPLACE(BT.Text, @Val3, ''))) /LEN(@Val3) AS val3
            FROM    @BaseTable AS BT
        ) AS subQ
```

Comment: The result looks like a table, [you can see it here](https://rextester.com/SDJL42258).
This is better than my result set earlier where I can [only get like this](https://rextester.com/UIO15840)

Comment: Is there a way to get only the total of it all?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a version of SQL Server older than 2016 and STRING_SPLIT is not available then an ordinal splitter function, such as [dbo.DelimitedSplit8K](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function), could be used to separate the words.

dbo.DelimitedSplit8K

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DelimitedSplit8K
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
```

Query

```
select count(*)
from #BaseTable bt
     cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(bt.[Text], ' ') ds
where ds.Item in ('the', 'when', 'wolf');
```

Output

```
9
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I was not able to test it since I'm probably using an old SQL service online compiler.

Comment: On the online compiler you posted the CREATE FUNCTION needs to be the first statement in a batch and separated from following statements by GO.  Then the temp table and query works.  Ordinal splitter is generally more efficient then replacement

Comment: Gordon's code gets rid of the period '.' which mine didn't do.  I would copy that and then use the splitter :)